# Сохранение консоли в файл

Tags: python

Как сохранить АБСОЛЮТНО все строки, которые выводятся в консоли?
logging не позволяет это сделать, она только сохраняет служебные сообщения, в обход ошибкам, принтам и тд​

Answer (score 0):

Не буду переубеждать, но логгинг - единственное правильное, протестированное и удобное решение сохранять все сообщения для приложения в файл. Все остальное - костыли, за исключением крайних случаев.

Первое, что надо сделать, это отказаться от `print` и использовать для этой функциональности уровень `debug` или `info` сущности `logging`.

Ошибки, исключения логгируются с помощью `error` и `exception` соответственно.

Второе, создать удобную конфигурацию логгирования, чтобы в консоль и в файл вы получали релевантную и если необходимо одинаковую информацию в едином формате, который вы так же можете определить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать перенаправление.

Допустим, у нас есть файл `program.py` и нам нужно сохранить его вывод в файл `program_output.txt`:

- Стандартный вывод:

  ```sh
  python program.py > program_output.txt
  ```
- Ошибки:

  ```sh
  python program.py 2> program_output.txt
  ```
- Всё вместе:

  ```sh
  python program.py > program_output.txt 2>&1
  ```

Comment: Да в винде тоже есть перенаправление, и очень похожее по синтаксису )